# ¿Cómo reporto un bug en la página de Stack Overflow?

Tags: soporte, meta, stackexchange

He encontrado un error en la página de Stack Overflow en español. Parece que es un bug. Considero que eso es un error **¿cómo debo proceder para reportar la incidencia?**

Comment: ¿A qué colas te refieres exactamente?

Comment: Es cierto da ese error cuando uno quiere editar la pregunta @Flxtr es en la cola de primeras publicaciones

Comment: Exacto, como dice Raul es en las colas de revisión, arriba a la derecha el botón de la carpeta con el visto.

Comment: @RaulCacacho entré a la cola de primeras publicaciones, [edité una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/92557) y no me marcó ningún error. Igual y un pantallazo nos daría una idea más clara de lo que está pasando

Comment: @Flxtr Eso pasa cuando la pregunta ya fue editada por alguien y la pregunta entra a la cola de revisión

Comment: @RaulCacacho ¿pero entonces no sería la cola de ediciones sugeridas? Aún no me queda lo suficientemente claro :(

Comment: @Flxtr Cuando entras a la cola de Primeras Publicaciones y la pregunta ya fue editada por otro usuario y tratas de editarla no muestra ningun error.

Comment: @track3r Puede esta pregunta mostrar algunas imagenes para que sea mas claros para los otros usuarios que no han tenido este problema

Comment: Es complicado capturar una pantalla del error cuando es precisamente que no sale el error, además hay que esperar que se de la circunstáncia que un mensaje en la cola de revisión, sea editado por un usuario y entonces tu, al intentarlo desde la cola de revisiones, no ves el error y simplemente no se entiende lo que ocurre hasta que te da por abrir la pregunta en ventana nueva y ahí si sale el aviso de error.

Comment: Si me ha pasado, en lugar de mostrar una alerta no hace nada, al dar click al botón de editar solo agrega el símbolo `#` a la URL. No he inspeccionado la consola para ver si marca algún error pero creo que debe existir un error al mostrar la alerta (?). Me ha pasado en la cola de revisión de primeras publicaciones

Comment: Reedito la pregunta de otra forma a ver si se entiende mejor.

Comment: Sigo sin entender. Si otro usuario inicia una edición, eso no bloquea a tu edición hasta que se envía

Comment: Son dos usuarios distintos: un usuario A publica una pregunta con errores en el título, la pregunta entra en revisión, otro usuario B edita la pregunta normalmente para corregirla, otro usuario C va a la cola de revisiones, ve la pregunta y sin abrirla le da a editar desde la propia lista para corregirla igual que el otro usuario B que aún está editando, el usuario C no podrá editarla porque está bloqueada, el problema es que no hay notificación alguna del motivo y eso parece un error.

Comment: Por cierto, si lees bien, en realidad no tienes que comprender el bug, ni saber qué existe, para mi es suficiente que dos o tres lo hayan confirmado, por lo que mi pregunta sigue siendo la misma, ¿cómo reporto el bug?

Comment: @track3r entendido. Los reportes de bug se hacen en Meta con la etiqueta [meta-tag:bug]... Es decir, esto **es** un reporte de bug.

Comment: Gracias Mariano

Comment: @Mariano, deberías publicarlo como respuesta y la aceptaría mientras alguien redactara una mejor.

Comment: @track3r El tema es que si esa es realmente la pregunta, iría etiquetada [meta-tag:soporte], y no necesitarías describir el bug, simplemente preguntar cómo reportar... Al estar etiquetada como [meta-tag:bug] y tener la descripción, ya es un reporte

Comment: He publicado el reporte, gracias @track3r!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La forma de reportar un bug es mediante una publicación en Meta usando la etiqueta [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

En el wiki de etiqueta de la etiqueta referida dice

> Cuando se reporta un bug, la pregunta debe incluir que fue lo que se
>   hizo para descubrir el bug, los pasos requeridos para replicar el
>   problema, el rendimiento del sistema, y el rendimiento esperado cuando
>   no existe el problema.
>
> Si es necesario proveer una explicación con más detalles, por favor
>   incluyan una captura de pantalla.

Referencias

- [¿Qué es Meta y cómo funciona?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)