# Error al intentar editar una pregunta que tiene una edición pendiente desde la cola de revisión

Tags: bug, colas-de-revisión

Partiendo de la publicación de [track3r](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/69897/track3r): [He encontrado un error en la página de https://es.stackoverflow.com ¿cómo debo proceder para reportar la incidencia?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3403/he-encontrado-un-error-en-la-p%c3%a1gina-de-https-es-stackoverflow-com-c%c3%b3mo-debo-p)

Por si sirve estoy utilizando Firefox 59.0.2 (64-bit) en macOS High Sierra 10.13.4

### Bug:

Yendo a la cola de revisión de [primeras publicaciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/), llegamos a una pregunta a la que queremos editar. Como ya hay una sugerencia de edición pendiente de aprobar y no tengo el [privilegio de aprobar sugerencias de edición](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), no pone el link a editar la pregunta, como normalmente lo haría y el `href` es un `#`

[image: bug en cola]

Tiene su `data-error` con el mensaje que despliega normalmente. **Damos click en editar y no pasa nada, solo agrega el `#` a la URL** (no tengo screenshot de eso :( )

---

### No bug:

Si damos click al link de editar, sin ir desde la cola de revisión, normalmente mostraría esta alerta

[image: alert diciendo que no se puede editar]

No vi ningún error en consola, y al parecer ambos links tienen lo mismo.

**PD:** Desde [Febrero 2018 - ¿un mes de revisiones malas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3284/febrero-2018-un-mes-de-revisiones-malas) parece que mas gente participa en las colas, me tomó tiempo esperar que exista una publicación por revisar para reproducir el error.

Comment: Gracias por el reporte KacosPro, ahora podré ver de primera mano como se desarrolla el problema, si me lo permites, he publicado tu pregunta como ejemplo de reporte en mi caso.

Comment: Gracias a ti @track3r, lo había visto hace tiempo pero pensé que era algo que solo me pasaba a mi :D

Comment: No parece haber mucho movimiento al respecto, ¿toca esperar o se puede hacer algo para agilizar la resolución?